# While creating a new folder in desktop folder it shows mkdir: cannot create directory ‘newfolder’: Bad message

Tags: filesystem

I am not able to download files in the download folder and am not able to create a new folder on the Desktop. I can create a folder in home. ls command also shows liks **ls: reading directory '.': Bad message** and mkdir shows **mkdir: cannot create directory' newfolder': Bad message** in Desktop.

Comment: You  should check your file system(s) by booting into live media.